# If columns have same value, assign a value next to it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have four separate columns:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 |  | 123 | value1 |
| 456 |  | 456 | value2 |
| 789 |  |  |  |

I want to assign column D values to column B if column A and C match. For example, B:1 should be assigned 'value1', B:2 will be 'value2' and B:3 will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell B1:

```
=if(A1=C1,D1,"")
```

For future reference consider looking a little harder for a solution before posting. The formula bears a pretty close resemblance to your actual question... "*if... a = c then...*"

Comment: Sorry I should've specified that the order of column C shouldn't matter. I believe this solution only works if the values in A and C are in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, $C$1:$D, 2, false))

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF((A1:A=C1:C)*(C1:C<>""), "value"&COUNTIFS(
 COUNTIFS(A1:A, C1:C, ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(C1:C)), 
 COUNTIFS(A1:A, C1:C, ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(C1:C)), 
 ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(C1:C)), ))
```

[image]